# What are DevOps & Ops user stories, or elements in scrum context?

Tags: architecture, operations, agile

What type of user stories should Operations write down while being asked to be a stakeholder in a scrum project?

Following this template:

"As Operations engineer, I want to.. in order to.."?!

My first idea is for example to come up with for example expectations to quality standards i.e. *acceptance criteria* to deliverables, like "as an operations engineer, I want to get deliverables accompanied with installation and validation automation scripts in order to enable fast and transparent deployments", but is there more to it?

Comment: What do you need that benefits you? Why do you need it? You can make it so generic that the story will never complete, or so specific that it need no further breakdown. For example, as an operations engineer I need feature_x implemented in script_y so that i can something_z.

Answer (score 7):

1. Make sure that your stories are not centered on Operations.  Remember that DevOps is a culture not a role.  Is an "Operations Engineer" really the stakeholder for the story?
2. Think of the features and business value they provide.  As a **stakeholder** I want **feature** so that **business value**. If you are struggling to identify the business value why are you doing it?
3. Stories are supposed to be "vertical slices" as opposed to "horizontal slices".  This means that stories should focus on an entire feature, not a layer.  This fits very well in a DevOps culture as your stories can cut across the traditional Development and Operations layers.

You already have some interesting features such as the quality standards. Now you just need to identify who the end stakeholder is, what the business value of this would be, and ensure that you write the story in such a way that people with development, operations, and possibly QA skill sets can work on it.